# Azure Bot access token reuse, is it possible?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I have developed azure bot application, I am using direct line token based approach to initiate azure chatbot from my web application. According to documentation token is valid for one hour and it expires automatically after one hour. The token can be refreshed before it expires. There are two questions.

1. We have observed that chat is going on even after one hour it continues in normal without any impact. So what does 1 hour expiry means? Is there any need to refresh the token for ongoing conversation?
2. Can the same access token be reused by any other client?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Bill for your detailed response. It works fine also. In our case we are using window.WebChat.renderWebChat. You can pass your token in your call. Internally it refreshes the token every 15 minutes. Please refer the GitHub documentation for the same. The token gets refreshed every 15 minutes, so there is no expiry of token possible if chat extends beyond 15 minutes. This refresh of token has not been mentioned in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You need the token just for the rendering of the webchat session. Thus once the webchat is open, you do not need the token any more and your conversation can carry on beyond 1 hour without issue. I suppose you could reuse the token to start a new webchat session within one hour, or refresh it to use it beyond that, but that seems unnecessary when you can just generate another token. Also, you almost certainly will want to pass a User attribute in the body of the token request so that you can store (and correctly retrieve) information from user state. Obviously you would not want to use this token for other clients in that case. I suppose you could reuse it if you are not using User State in your bot, but I wouldn't recommend it and again I think it would be more work this way.

I'm assuming you already have some of this set, but here is how I am creating the endpoint to create a token in my bot:

```js
server.post('/directline/token', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        var body = {User:{Id:req.body.userId}};
        const response = await request({
            url: 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.DIRECTLINE_SECRET}`},
            json: body,
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            timeout: 10000
        });
        const token = response.token;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write(token);
        res.end();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.writeHead(500);
        res.write('Call to retrieve token from Direct Line failed');
        res.end();
    }
})
```

I'm sending along the userId from my webpage which I'm showing below. You'll need to hit this endpoint from the script wherever you are deploying the bot (this is assuming you are using botframework-webchat CDN). Here is the code I used for that.

```js
    const response = await fetch('https://YOURAPPSERVICE.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({userId:userID})
    });
    const token = await response.text();
```

Body of request must be stringified JSON. The userID is just a cookie which the webpage retrieves and/or sets before the bot is rendered. `Fetch` returns the response as a stream, so you need to convert it using `.text()` or `.json()` depending on how you are sending the response from your bot endpoint (I used `.text()`, if you want to use JSON you'll need to set up your token endpoint to return it instead of text like I did above). You need to await both the `fetch` *AND* the `response.text()`. My whole script to deploy the webchat is within an async function.